# C# How to avoid passing arguments when using IoC resolver

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automation, inversion-of-control

I have recently began experimenting with dependency injection and IoC.

Here is an issue that bothers me...
I have a dependency resolver, that basically allows me to do the following

```
injection.Register<IMyInterface, MySpecificType>();
```

This will automatically resolve the type, whenever something in the code asks for it and provide `MySpecificType` as an implementation for `IMyInterface`.

This works great for Controllers in ASP.NET for example, where the controller constructor has no parameters and is also dynamically invoked by the framework.

But what happens if I have my own custom class (in this case `MySpecificType`), and I want to dynamically resolve it. That is, whenever something in my code requires `IMyInterface`, the resolver should pass in `MySpecificType`.

Here is an example :

```
injection.Register<IMyInterface, MySpecificType>();


public SomeClass(IMyInterface dependency)
{
   //do something
}
```

Then somewhere in my code I wish to create a new instance of`SomeClass`.

```
var instance = new SomeClass(//What do i pass here)
```

What should I pass in the constructor. Ofcourse I could do something like `new MySpecificType()`, but this would make my automatic dependency resolver pointless.  Should I have a separate empty constuctor and use that or is this something that cannot happen.

Comment: I'd say that it depends on the IoC framework you're using...

Comment: If a class can't be resolved as part of the complete object graph, it probably means you are trying to inject _runtime data_ into it. You should prevent doing this: [don't compose application components using runtime data](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask your IoC container to instantiate your class for you. Then it really depends on your IoC container.

For example, with autofac

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MyComponent>().As<IService>();
var container = builder.Build();

using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var service = scope.Resolve<IService>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Obivously it will depend on the specific container, but I was wondering what the general approach to this problem is.
Cheers